# Throwing two dice probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

We got the following problem from last week. They say my solution is not correct, but I don't know where I go wrong.

**Problem:**
We throw with two dice until the sum of the results equals $10$ two times. What is the probability that we throw exactly eight times a sum smaller than $10$ until this event occurs?

(For example if we throw the first time $3$,$4$, second time $5$,$5$ and third time $6$,$4$ then we finish the experiment. The sums until the second $10$ were $7$,$10$ and $10$.)

**My solution:**
The probability of throwing exactly $10$ in one throw is

$$p_{\left(=10\right)}\overset{\cdot}{=}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)=3\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{2}.$$

The probability of throwing more than $10$ in one throw is

$$p_{\left(>10\right)}\overset{\cdot}{=}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)=3\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{2}.$$

So the probability of throwing less than $10$ in one round is

$$p_{\left(<10\right)}\overset{\cdot}{=}1-3\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{2}-3\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{2}=1-6\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{2}.$$

The probability of throwing $\xi=1$ "exactly $10$" and throwing $\eta=8$ "less than $10$" from $N-1=n$ throwings is

$$\mathbf{P}\left(\xi=1,\eta=8\right)=\frac{n!}{1!8!\left(n-1-8\right)!}p_{\left(=10\right)}^{1}p_{\left(<10\right)}^{8}\left(1-p_{\left(=10\right)}-p_{\left(<10\right)}\right)^{n-1-8}.$$

The distribution of the number of the last throwing can be calculated as follows:

$$\mathbf{P}\left(N=m\right)=\frac{\left(m-1\right)!}{1!8!\left(\left(m-1\right)-1-8\right)!}p_{\left(=10\right)}^{1}p_{\left(<10\right)}^{8}\left(1-p_{\left(=10\right)}-p_{\left(<10\right)}\right)^{\left(m-1\right)-1-8}\cdot p_{\left(=10\right)}$$

So the asked probability using the total law of probabilities is:

$$\sum_{n=9}^{\infty}\mathbf{P}\left(\left(\xi=1,\eta=8\right)\cap\left(N-1=n\right)\right)=\sum_{n=9}^{\infty}\mathbf{P}\left(\xi=1,\eta=8\mid N-1=n\right)\cdot\mathbf{P}\left(N-1=n\right)=$$

$$=\sum_{n=9}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{1!8!\left(n-1-8\right)!}p_{\left(=10\right)}^{1}p_{\left(<10\right)}^{8}\left(1-p_{\left(=10\right)}-p_{\left(<10\right)}\right)^{n-1-8}\cdot\frac{n!}{1!8!\left(n-1-8\right)!}p_{\left(=10\right)}^{1}p_{\left(<10\right)}^{8}\left(1-p_{\left(=10\right)}-p_{\left(<10\right)}\right)^{n-1-8}\cdot p_{\left(=10\right)}$$, which is $\simeq0.0047101892$ according to WolframAlpha.

Can you see my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what your random variables $\ \xi\ $ and $\ \eta\ $ are supposed  to be. If you take $\ \xi_n\ $ to be the number of times you throw exactly $10$ in the first $\ n\ $ throws, and $\ \eta_n\ $ to be the number of times you throw something strictly less than $10$ in the first $\ n\ $ throws, then you get
\begin{align}
P\big(\xi_n=1,\eta_n=8\big)&=\frac{n!}{1!\,8!\,(n-1-8)!}p^1_{(=10)}p^8_{(<10)}\big(1-p^1_{(=10)}-p^1_{(<10)}\big)^{(n-1-8)}\\
&=\frac{n!}{1!\,8!\,(n-9)!}\left(\frac{1}{12}\right)^{n-8}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^8\ ,
\end{align}
which is the formula which you give for your $\ P(\xi=1,\eta=8)\ $.  I'm therefore guessing that your $\ \xi\  $ and $\ \eta\ $ are meant to be the same things that I have called  $\ \xi_n\ $ and $\ \eta_n\ $.  If that's the case, then omitting  the explicit dependence on $\ n\ $ makes your exposition confusing, and I expect that might be one of the things that's led you astray.

Let $\ T_n\ $ be the value of the $\ n^\text{th}\ $ throw.  If $\ N\ $ is the number of the last throw, then $\ N=m\ $ if and only if $\ \xi_{m-1}=1\ $ and $\ T_m=10 $ *regardless of the value of $\ \eta_m\ $* because you've specified that the experiment finishes as soon as you've thrown $10$ exactly twice, irrespective of how many times you've thrown something less than $10$. Therefore
\begin{align}
P(N=m)&=P\big(\xi_{m-1}=1, T_m=10\big)\\
&={m-1\choose1}p_{(=10)}\big(1-p_{(=10)}\big)^{m-2}p_{(=10)}\\
&=(m-1)\left(\frac{11^{m-2}}{12^m}\right)
\end{align}
rather than the expression you've given for this quantity.  Note that $\ \sum_\limits{i=2}^\infty(m-1)\left(\frac{11^{m-2}}{12^m}\right)=1\ ,$ which is the correct value for $\ P\left(\bigcup_\limits{m=2}^\infty\{N=m\}\right)\ $, whereas expression you've given for $\ P(N=m)\ $ doesn't give $\ 1\ $ when you sum it from $\ m=2\ $ to $\ \infty\ $.

The probability you're looking for is
\begin{align}
P\big(\xi_{N-1}=1,\eta_{N-1}=8\big)&=\sum_{m=2}^\infty P\big(\xi_{N-1}=1,\eta_{N-1}=8,N=m \big)\\
&=\sum_{m=10}^\infty P\big(\xi_{m-1}=1,\eta_{m-1}=8,N=m \big)\\
&=\sum_{m=10}^\infty P\big(\xi_{m-1}=1,\eta_{m-1}=8,T_m=10\big)\\
&=\sum_{m=10}^\infty P\big(\xi_{m-1}=1,\eta_{m-1}=8\big)P\big(T_m=10\big)\\
&=\sum_{m=10}^\infty\frac{(m-1)!}{1!\,8!\,(m-10)!}\left(\frac{1}{12}\right)^{m-8}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^8\ ,
\end{align}
because $\ P\big(\xi_{m-1}=1,\eta_{m-1}=8,N=m \big)=0\ $ for $\ m\le9\ $, and $ \ T_m\ $ and $\ \big(\xi_{m-1},\eta_{m-1}\big)\ $ are independent. Wolfram alpha [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum++5%5E8*factorial%28m-1%29%2F%28factorial%288%29*factorial%28m-10%29*12%5E%28m-8%29*6%5E8%29%2C+m%3D10+to+infinity+) $\ \frac{9\times10^8}{11^{10}}=\frac{900\ 000\ 000}{25\ 737\ 424\ 601}\approx$$\,0.034699\ $ for the value of this sum. I have now confirmed that  $\ \frac{9\times10^8}{11^{10}}\ $  is indeed the exact probability by a completely different method—namely, by treating the process as a Markov chain and calculating the probability that the chain will end up in the appropriate one of its two absorbing states.

Comment: Is it possible that you have mixed up the value of $p_{\left(<10\right)}$ and $p_{\left(>10\right)}$? Anyway, I agree with you that my formula for $\mathbf{P}(N=m)$ was wrong and it is indeed irrespective of $\eta_m$

Comment: Yes, I does  look like  I've mixed up  the values of $\ p_{(<10)}\ $ and $\ p_{(>10)}\ $, which means that the numerical value I obtained for the probability will be wrong.

Comment: I've now (hopefully) corrected the numerical values of the probabilities, and checked the answer with the Markov chain method.

Answer (score 3):

I can totally follow you (and agree with you) up to and including the formula for $P(\xi=1, \eta=8)$. Since that formula contains an $n$, I'd make it explicit and call it $P(\xi=1, \eta=8, N=n+1)$

Then I assume that $P(N=m)$ is supposed to mean the probabiliy that the whole procedure ends with a 'good' result after the $m$-th throw. If that is true, I also agree with you and your formula can be rewritten as

$$P(N=m) = p_{(=10)}P(\xi=1, \eta=8, N=m),$$

representing the fact that for the procedure to end 'good' at the $m$-th throw, that throw has to be a $10$ and before that you need exactly $\xi=1$ sum of $10$ and exactly $\eta=8$ sums of less than 10.

What you should have done is to calculate

$$\sum_{m=10}^\infty P(N=m),$$

because that sums the probabilities that your procedure ends with a 'good' result after exactly $10,11,12,\ldots$ throws.

By summing over the product $P(\xi=1, \eta=8, N=m)P(N=m)$, your treat those 2 events whose probability you multiply as independent, which they are not.

Maybe the cause was in notation, as $P(N=m)$ might have started as "the probability that the $m$-th throw is a $10$", but that is of course only a guess.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach using exponential generating functions.

The probablity of rolling a number less than $10$ is $30/36$, that of rolling a $10$ is $3/36$, and the probability of rolling a number greater than $10$ is $3/36$.

Consider the situation just before rolling the second $10$: we must have exactly $8$ rolls less than $10$, exactly one $10$, and an arbitrary number of rolls greater than $10$.  For brevity, let's say that is a "favorable" state. We want the exponential probability generating function for the probability of being in a favorable state on the $n$th roll, i.e. we want
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} p_n x^n$$
where $p_n$ is the probability of being in a favorable state on the $n$th roll.

The probability EGF for a sequence of $8$ rolls less than $10$ is $(1/8!) (30/36)^8 x^8$, that for exactly one roll of $10$ is $(3/36) x$, and that for an arbitrary number of rolls greater then $10$ is $\exp((3/36) x)$; so
$$f(x) = (1/8!) \left( \frac{30}{36} \right)^8 x^8 \cdot \frac{3}{36} x \cdot \exp \left( \frac{3}{36} x \right) \tag{*}$$

The probability of having exactly $8$ rolls less than $10$ when the second $10$ is rolled is
$$\frac{3}{36} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p_n$$
so we would like a way to sum this series.  Fortunately, there is a way by use of the identity $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} x^n \;dx = n!$:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p_n = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} f(x) \;dx$$
Substituting for $f(x)$ from $(*)$ and evaluating the integral (I used Mathematica), the result is
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p_n = \frac{10800000000}{25937424601}$$
so the answer to the problem is
$$\frac{3}{36} \cdot \frac{10800000000}{25937424601} = \frac{900000000}{25937424601} = \boxed{0.0346989}$$
(This result is consistent with a Monte Carlo simulation.)